# Calling a function within a class instead of function using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In the Python [documentation on multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) there are numerous examples of parallelizing the work of a function. I assumed it would also be possible to do this of a function contained in a class. However the following example does not work. 
It spawns for processes that calculate the multiplication of 2 of the current process number. Reporting the calculated value inside the object works, however when I try to get the calculated value after the jobs are finished it just reports back the value set in the constructor.

Class definition

```
import multiprocessing


class MyClass():

    def __init__(self,runname):
        self.runname = runname
        self.output = 0



    def calculate(self,input):
        self.output = input*2
        print "Reporting from runname %s, calculation yielded %s" % (self.runname,self.output)


    def getOutput(self):
        return self.output
```

Code to call the object:

```
objectList = [] #Store objects
jobList = [] #Store multiprocessing objects

#Run the workers in  4 parallel processes
for i in range(4):

    thisRunname = 'Worker:%s' % i
    thisInstance = MyClass(thisRunname)

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=thisInstance.calculate, args=(i,))

    jobList.append(p)
    p.start()
    objectList.append(thisInstance)

for thisJob in jobList: #Wait till all jobs are done
    thisJob.join()

print "Jobs finished"

for thisInstance in objectList:
    print "Worker %s calculated %s " % (thisInstance.runname,thisInstance.getOutput() )
```

**This outputs:**

```
Reporting from runname Worker:0, calculation yielded 0
Reporting from runname Worker:1, calculation yielded 2
Reporting from runname Worker:2, calculation yielded 4
Reporting from runname Worker:3, calculation yielded 6
Jobs finished
Worker Worker:0 calculated 0
Worker Worker:1 calculated 0
Worker Worker:2 calculated 0
Worker Worker:3 calculated 0
```

So the calculate function can be spawned without problem, when trying to retrieve the calculated value it just gives back 0, the value it was set to in the constructor.

Is there a key concept I'm missing, how is it possible to obtain the self.output value?

Comment: Maybe these might help (Each subprocess updates its own copy of MyClass .output and therefore main process's output is not affected): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244745/how-to-use-classes-with-python-multiprocessing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666559/cannot-change-class-variables-with-multiprocessing-process-object-in-python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialization provided by the `Process` class is only one-way. It will serialize the `target` and `args` you give it, but it doesn't bring anything back automatically.

So when you create your `Process`es, the `multiprocessing` module pickles the `MyClass` instances you've created (since the `target`s are bound methods of the instances) and each one gets unpickled it in one of the child processes. This is why each of the children does the calculation as you expect.

However, the changes to the child process's version of the instance don't ever get copied back to the main process. There's simply no mechanism to do it. In the end the instances get thrown away when the child process ends. The parent process's instances of `MyClass` are not updated, which is why you see the `calculated 0` messages.